# $\int_I f\,dm\geq\vert I\vert$ for any interval $I$, prove $f(x)\geq 1\text{ a.e.}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Problem:

> $f$ is Lebesgue integrable function defined on $[a,b]$, and $\int_I f\,dm\geq\vert I\vert$ for any interval $I\subset [a,b]$. Prove $f(x)\geq 1 \text{ a.e. } x\in [a,b]$

As open sets can be written as the union of countable disjoint open intervals, $\int_G f\,dm\geq m(G)$ for any open set $G\subset[a,b]$. Then I try to approximate the measurable set $\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)<1\}$ with an open set and hope this would be helpful, but it does not work. I am afraid this may not be the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've shown that $\int_G f\, dm \ge |G|$ for all open sets $G\subset [a,b]$, use the monotone convergence theorem to show $\int_H f\, dm \ge |H|$ whenever $H$ is the countable intersection of a decreasing sequence of open sets. Next, if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $[a,b]$, there is a set $H$ as previously described containing $A$ such that $H - A$ is a null set. Use this fact to show that $\int_A f\, dm \ge |A|$.

Consider the sets $S_n := \{x\in [a,b] : f(x) < 1 - 1/n\}$ for all $n\ge 1$. Those sets increase to $S := \{x\in [a,b] : f(x) < 1\}$, so it suffices to show that $|S_n| = 0$ for all $n$. Now $$|S_n| = \int_{S_n} 1\, dm \ge \int_{S_n} \left(f + \frac{1}{n}\right)\, dm \ge |S_n| + \frac{1}{n}|S_n|$$ so that $0 \ge\frac1{n}|S_n|$, or $|S_n| = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I know that for any measurable set $E$, there exists a $G_\delta$ set $F\supset E$
 such that $m(F\setminus E)=0$. But why "if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $[a,b]$, there is a set $H$ as previously described containing $A$ such that $H-A$ is a **null set**"?

Comment: @Guanfei by a null set I mean a set of Lebesgue measure zero. For each $j \ge 1$, take an open set $O_j\supset A$ such that $m(O_j \setminus A) < 2^{-j}$. Set $H_j = O_1 \cap \cdots \cap O_j$. Then $\{H_j\}$ is a decreasing sequence of open sets containing $A$ such that $m(H_j \setminus A) \le 2^{-j}$. Define $H = \cap_j H_j$. Then $H \supset A$ and $m(H \setminus A) \le m(H_j \setminus A) \le 2^{-j}$ for all $j$ so that $m(H \setminus A) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Lebesgue's Theorem:---** Here one can use a lemma related Hardy-Littlewood maximal function
> which says that for a locally Lebesgue integrable function $\varphi$ defined over
> $\Bbb R^n$ we have $$\lim_{r\to
>  0+}\frac{1}{m(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)}\varphi(y)\,dy=\varphi(x)\text{ a.e. } x\in
> \Bbb R^n.$$

See Folland's Real Analysis Theorem 3.18 for proof.

Note that according to the statement we have $\frac{\int_I f\ dm}{|I|}\geq 1$ for any interval $I\subseteq(a,b)$, so that $$f(x)=\lim_{r\to 0+}\frac{1}{m\big((x-r,x+r)\big)}\int_{(x-r,x+r)}f\ dm \geq 1\text{ for almost every }x\in (a,b).$$

Comment: The result you are using called Lebesgue's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, this is a problem in my exam, and I have not been taught this Lebesgue theorem. So I think that there should be a solution that avoids using this theorem.

Comment: The main tool that one uses to prove this lemma is every Lebesgue integrable function can be approximated by a continuous Lebesgue integrable function w.r.t. $L^1$ norm.